# avoid eval for the sake of eval Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, parfor

I'm currently evaluating my arrays as `eval(['P' num2str(jj) '(i,:)'])` where `P1` `P2` are my arrays, and I'm only interested all both my arrays from `(i,1:3)` and where `i` is used to *rows* and `jj` for evaluating `1` `2` arrays. I want to avoid `eval()` as I want to use *PCT* for *parallel processing* of both arrays, as `parfor` loop doesn't support `eval()` and also *Matlab* also suggests that avoid it wherever U can, Now what are the possible solutions/suggestions according to my scenario.

**My Code:**

```
n=2;
for i=1:10
for jj=1:n
eval(['P' num2str(jj) '(i,:)']);
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a cell array:

```
P = cell(1,2);
P{1} = P1;
P{2} = P2;
```

Now you can do it like this:

```
n=2;
for i=1:10
    for jj=1:n
        P{jj}(i,:)
    end
end
```

Comment: seems cool, but some other approach would be better as I want to avoid `P1` and `P2` also. Can U pls suggest some other option if any in your mind?

Comment: Well, perhaps you could do that assignment, then run `clear P1 P2` to clear them from memory and, from now on, use only `P{}`.